# Not able to delete one of default routes

Tags: linux, networking, routing

In my Linux server (4.9.9_1 kernel, x86_64) `enp5s0` has a static ip `192.168.1.30` and `enp9s0` is given an address via `dhcpcd`.

```
# ip route ls
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp5s0 src 192.168.1.30 metric 202 
default via 39.53.131.254 dev enp9s0 src 39.53.131.237 metric 203 
39.53.130.0/23 dev enp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 39.53.131.237 metric 203 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.30 metric 202
```

The first thing I don't understand is why does the system set two default routes, although preference is given to one based on `metric`.

What I want to do is to delete the second default route `via 39.53....`, to add another routing table, set `ip rule` for that to add an identical default route but for the new routing table.

When:

```
# ip route del default via 39.53.131.254 dev enp9s0
# echo $?
0
```

The routing table doesn't seem to have changed, though:

```
    # ip route l
    default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp5s0 src 192.168.1.30 metric 202 
    default via 39.53.131.254 dev enp9s0 src 39.53.131.237 metric 203
39.53.130.0/23 dev enp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 39.53.131.237 metric 203 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.30 metric 202
```

After a `ip route flush cache`:

`# ip route show cache`

shows nothing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

After help on Freenode IRC ##linux channel.
As `dhcpcd` was responsible for the IP address of `enp9s0`, the way to clear the routes passing through the interface is to flush the device:
`ip addr flush dev enp9s0`.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, but many years after, I bumped into similar situation n Debian Buster.

There where constantly something messing up with my default routes, and the reason was systemd connman.service.

Finally I found logs:

```
journalctl -n -u connman.service
br0 {add} route 192.168.1.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
br0 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
enp5s0 {add} address 169.254.208.64/16 label enp5s0 family 2
enp5s0 {add} route 169.254.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
enp5s0 {add} route 0.0.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 scope 253 <LINK>
```

and thats it, internet is gone.

Fixed by totally removing service:

```
systemctl stop connman.service
systemctl disable connman.service
systemctl mask connman.service
```